# Update NGRX/Redux store object property

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects

The scenario in my Angular application is, user clicks on "ShowDetails" which should displays a form with the details of the selected item which I already loaded at startup, but not the details and I don't want to load all the details OnInit.

I'm able to dispatch an action successfully, but I want to have an Effect which should get the id (I assume from the store), make a http call, fetch the detail for that item and add it as a property to the master item so that subsequent calls do not go to the service again. I can do all these.

My question is I do not sure how to update the property of the master object in the store without mutating the original object in the store (which I know I shouldn't) so subsequent calls don't call the service again. Or how do I update the property in the Effect, before it gets to the Reducer for final processing? Ideally, I will like to show an empty form page, with loading icon, before the details returns.

Comment: In your effect, don't dispatch an http request if the item is already fetched. Instead simply dispatch an action saying that the item data is ready. - Do you know how to do that?

Comment: The item would not be fetched the first time so i need to fetch and update the property of the master object which already exists in the store.

Comment: The effect will choose to do one of two things: If the data is already fetched, it will dispatch the action saying that item data is ready, otherwise it will initiate an ajax request, at the end of which that item ready action will be dispatched. - In your child component, you display the loading icon until the item data ready action is received. - I'm goint to post an answer with an example of how I did this in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your effect needs to choose whether the data requested is already in the store, and only if it isn't, it should initiate an AJAX request to fetch it. And in both cases once data is ready, dispatch a "data ready" action.

Here's how I did it in the past:

```js
export class MyEffects {
  constructor(private store$: Store<fromStore.AppState>,
    private action$: Actions,
    private backend: MyService,
  ) { }

  @Effect()
  fetchData$ = this.action$.ofType<fromActions.FetchDataAction>(fromActions.FETCHDATA).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(x => x.main.cacheMap)),
    switchMap(([action, cacheMap]) => this.fetchData(action.id, cacheMap)),
    map(r => r new fromActions.DataReadyAction(r)),
  );

  fetchData(id: string, cacheMap: { [key: string]: Item }): Observable<Item> {
    if (!cacheMap[id]) {
      return this.backend.getData(id);
    } else {
      return of({ ...cacheMap[id] });
    }
  }
}
```

Notice a few things:

- The effects class constructor has the store injected into it.
- The effect itself uses `withLatestFrom` to obtain the latest copy of the state.
- The `fetchData` function chooses whether to send an AJAX request or return immediately based on the existence of the requested key in the `cacheMap` variable which is part of the store.

When the `DataReady` action is reduced, the new item is placed in the cache map of the state, so that subsequent `FetchData` actions don't re-request it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the example. In my case, i have an object called Order in my redux  store already which has a property called details but which is null initially. After fetching the order detail using the example above,  where is the right place to set order.details = data? So its updated in the store.  In this same Effect? So its not fetched again.

Comment: The place to set `order.details = data` is in the reduce of the `DataReady` action.